# How to compare two unsaved pieces of texts in Vim?

Tags: gvim

What I want to do is:
(1) Copy a piece of code and paste into a buffer in Vim;
(2) Copy another piece of code and paste into another buffer in Vim;
(3) Compare these two buffers directly without saving them into files.

I know this can be done easily with Notepad++. I need to do this quite often, and I want to know if Vim can do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the code pasted into your buffers, go to each buffer and execute

```
:diffthis
```

If those two are the only buffers in your vim session, you can execute this one command instead:

```
:windo diffthis
```